# Solve the equation |x-1|=x-1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, absolute-value

Solve the equation:$|x-1|=x-1$

My solution:

Case 1 :$ x\ge1$, Hence $x-1=x-1$, therefore infinite solution

Case 2 :$ x<1$, Hence $1-x=x-1$,$x=1$, hence no solution

But the solution i saw concept used is $ x\le1$ in lieu of $ x<1$

Hence final answer is $[1,\infty]$, is this concept correct

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: Take a case |x-a|=1

Comment: Slight error... make the right bracket (right of the $\infty$) a right parenthesis.  In other words, the solution set should be $$[1,\infty)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

My solution: if $|x-1|=x-1$, then $x-1 \ge 0$, hence $x \ge 1$. For $x \ge 1$ your equations reads as follows: $x-1=x-1$.

Hence: $|x-1|=x-1 \iff x \ge 1.$

Answer (score 2):

If you were to make case 1 cover $x \gt 1$ and case 2 cover $x \le 1$ then you would get a similar answer for case 1, i.e. all such $x \in (1,\infty)$ satisfy the equation

while for case 2: $\qquad1-x=x-1 \implies x=1$

and your combined solution would then be $x \in (1,\infty) \cup \{1\} = [1,\infty)$, the same solution as your original method

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is right, apart from the square bracket pointed out in @ElevenEleven's comment ($\infty$ can't be the upper end of a closed interval).

Another way to get it is to note that $|a|=a$ only when $a\geq 0$, so for $a=x-1$,

$$|x-1|=x-1$$ implies $$x-1\geq 0$$

which gives you the answer without needing to consider different cases.

Answer (score 1):

Nicely done! Ultimately, you don't need to consider the second case, since $\lvert t\rvert\neq t$ for $t<0,$ but it doesn't hurt to be thorough. The only thing to change about your conclusion is from $[1,\infty]$ to $[1,\infty),$ as "$\infty$" is a notational convention and not a real number.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1142508)

Comment: @Adam: I am not the OP. I answered the OP's question, and edited the question's tags. If you are going to review things, please be more careful in the future.

Comment: When I reviewed the answer, it said exactly this: 
"Nicely done! That's about the most straightforward approach you could take." It's been edited since.

Comment: True. At no point did it say "Thank you!"

Comment: Indeed. Canned response. You said "Nicely done." Instead of undeleting your non-answer and then adding an answer, why not just add a new answer?

Comment: For many proof verification questions, a canned response is all that is called for. The only reason I said more than "yes" is that there is a minimum character count for answers. My original answer certainly wasn't worth upvoting, but did not warrant deletion. The downvote led me to notice the OPs character error, though, so that was constructive. As for why I didn't post a new answer: that would clutter the page for higher-rep users. Better to simply make improvements and clarifications.